# Inserting timestamp in oracle timestamp column

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, timestamp

I am trying to insert the timestamp(6) data type value into the table by using following code:

```
INSERT INTO TOY_STORE (TOY_STORE_ID,TOY_STORE_NAME,CITY,PHONENUMBER,STORE_OPENING_TIME,STORE_CLOSING_TIME)
    VALUES(1,'Kid''s Cave','Delhi',9912312312,'2014-04-01 09:10:12','2014-04-01 21:42:05');
```

But it is giving be error 
SQL Error: ORA-01843: not a valid month
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
*Cause:
*Action:
Can someone rectify my code

Answer (score 2):

Oracle has a non-standard format for date.  You can use that format (DD/MMM/YYYY), use the `to_date()` function, or the `DATE`/`TIMESTAMP` operator.  I think this will work:

```
INSERT INTO TOY_STORE (TOY_STORE_ID,T OY_STORE_NAME, CITY,PHONENUMBER, 
                       STORE_OPENING_TIME, STORE_CLOSING_TIME)
    VALUES(1, 'Kid''s Cave',' Delhi', 9912312312,
           TIMESTAMP '2014-04-01 09:10:12', TIMESTAMP '2014-04-01 21:42:05');
```

Comment: The "*DATE/TIMESTAMP operator*" is actually standard ANSI SQL to write a date/timestamp literal (and my preferred way to do so). Oracle's date format is not "non-standard", because every other way of writing a date/timestamp literal is non-standard as well and subject to implicit data type conversion (which depends on the locale settings of the client)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Although you are correct, I think ISO standard formats should be accepted anywhere -- and most databases to recognize them.

Answer (score 0):

You can also execute this command before you do your insert:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';
```